# why isnt line "print("guys listen")" not working?

Tags: python, decorator

```
def amn(func):
    def inner():
        print("guys listen")
    func()
    return inner

@amn
def damn():
    print("hey")
```

amn is a decorator. The function inner() is supposed to be called when amn is executed. But for some reason, it is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
@amn
def foo():
    pass
```

Is the same as

```py
def foo():
    pass

foo = amn(foo)
```

Your `amn` calls the original `damn` as `func()`, and then the `@` operator assigns the return value of amn back to damn, making it `inner`.

You shouldn't invoke `func` in the outer part of `amn` but as part of `inner`. You should also look at [functools.wraps](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.wraps).

Comment: It doesn't print anything when I add func() inside inner(). I know what amn does. Just stuck here.

Comment: Put func() inside inner. Then call `damn` at the module level after you've decorated it and see what happens.